# A good tutorial for jQuery or JavaScript Sticky Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins

I am trying to find a decent tutorial or code sample of how to achieve a common effect I see around the web.  Essentially its having an element attach itself to the top of the window when it meets the element while scrolling.  Quite frankly I have no idea what to call this functionality, or how to go about searching for the specifics of achieving it.

Here is on example, from the [Twitter Bootstrap Docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html).  The bar under the heading & sub-heading will attach itself to the window as it scrolls past to help you navigate the page.

Another example is on the [Android Developers Pages](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html).  The left side navigation element will attach itself to the window on scroll.

Any assistance in this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance & cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [jquery-waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) and the [Sticky Elements Example](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/).

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Thank you so much!  Its telling me I have to wait 10 minutes to accept as an answer, but I will accept when available.

Answer (score 1):

use `position:sticky` for sticky elements.

Here is the article explained.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

[sticky position demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  I checked out the demo in Chrome and it said unsupported.  However it did work in Canary, so unfortunately this is not practical for a real-world project quite yet. Though I am super happy to see the specification implemented.